# Can Stack Overflow for Teams have multiple sites like Stack Exchange does?

Tags: support, status-deferred, stack-overflow-for-teams

Stack Exchange obviously has numerous sites organized by topic, such as [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/), Stack Overflow, The Workplace, and Personal Finances. Each of those has separate privileges, separate membership, separate color and logo themes, etc. Can you do something similar for Stack Overflow for Teams?

Comment: Wouldn't that essentially be another team?

Comment: @Makoto I'm a little confused as to whether that would be the same thing or not. For example, if you're on two separate teams, do you have separate reputation on each team?

Comment: ...Likely, yes.  Unless you're looking for some kind of abstraction beyond that, everything that I know about Teams is that they're isolated and separate from every other team.

Comment: @EJoshuaS from someone who is on 2 teams, absolutely yes. Consider each team as each site on SE instead: independent from each other (ignore association bonus for completeness).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, we have no plans to support this use case. If you need multiple teams, you'll need to purchase additional teams. That said, we are thinking about it, but it's not going to be resolved in the near term. We'll probably revisit this request sometime next year.