# Does Stack Overflow for Teams have a pricing model that supports large organizations?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

Currently, the listed price for Stack Overflow Enterprise is $17 per user, which is fine for small organizations but would be a sizable investment for a moderately-sized organization (over $1 million a year for 5000 users) and prohibitively expensive for large organizations.

Does Stack Exchange offer any pricing model that's tailored towards organizations that have a very large user base?

Comment: It’s unlikely a 5000 employee company would need licenses for all their users. And even if they did, in the grand scheme of things an additional 204 bucks per employee per year is not that much. Yes, 1.000.000 it’s a big number, but for a company with that many users, if the product solves an actual need and provides value? Not so much, I think.

Comment: @yivi $17 per month, so $204 per year. That doesn't sound like a lot, but it adds up really quickly.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize they now had public pricing for Enterprise... I'd suggest you probably want to contact Sales directly, and see if they are willing to negotiate a private arrangement. They probably wouldn't want to publish that here. (Not sure how to do that... maybe you need to request a demo first, then someone will reach out? I wonder.)

Comment: "$10,000 minimum spend per month to speak to a Sales Rep"  lol

Comment: @yivi $1 million for something that only covers a small portion of your employee base is hardly pocket change, though. That's a tough sell to management.

Comment: @yivi Besides, [it's not necessarily the case that you only use it for developers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385969/can-stack-overflow-for-teams-have-multiple-sites-like-stack-exchange-does). There's no particular reason you can't use it for other kinds of stuff too, like general IT support or our finance teams. I also think that it would be cool to have a Meta site for questions and discussion about the company itself (including management announcements, for example).

Comment: A company of 5,000 individuals probably isn't going to have the same degree of vertical integration as a team of, say, 150-200 individuals, so I would see a large organization elect to chunk out use of Teams., especially as a trial (no one spends that kind of cash on an experiment).  I suppose this question comes from a question of how a service like this is actually used.  How do you actually see 5,000 users using a system for Teams to organize and share information?

Comment: @Makoto Presumably, your entire user base wouldn't be on the same team necessarily. Although, maybe for stuff like general IT support there would be a team for that so that your helpdesk isn't continually deluged with the same questions for the Nth time.

Comment: ...and you have a help desk 5,000 deep?  And they all require their own individual accounts to Teams so that they can...read this?

Comment: @Jeremy Yeah, the listed price makes it difficult to even propose as a serious idea TBH though, it would be a little embarrassing if I got permission to do a RFI/POC and had to come back and say "oh, by the way, will you give me a couple million dollars for this?"

Comment: @Makoto No, my help desk isn't nearly that big - I was referring to other users who may want to post and/or read questions for the help desk. I'd just rather spare our help desk from having to answer the same questions over and over again if there was a way to help out with that.

Comment: The company I work for uses a rough draft of a horrible bit of forum software that was written in the early 90's by some kids in a college dorm room and has yet to be updated once. They use it for the same purpose you're proposing and they have thousands of dealers across the globe where every employee from every dealership uses this software. I have previously suggested the use of the Stack Exchange Enterprise service, but it was deemed cost-prohibitive, given that there are currently more than 500,000 users on the current forum software. $102,000,000.00 per year is a bit much.

Comment: @TinyGiant Yeah, that's kind of what I'm up against. I can't exactly ask them for that kind of money for it. Maybe our companies should lobby for a deal for organizations like ours.

Comment: The answer to the converse of the question is that any large company with any respect for software methodology will have and maintain a best-practices wiki, codings standards, automated review tools, test harness, related blogs and so on.

Comment: The fundamental logic here is a bit a weird: if $17/user is a reasonable price for a small organisation, why isn't it a reasonable price for a large one? The size of the organisation has already been taken into account by the "per user" pricing. If employees in a small org are made at least $17 per month more valuable, why wouldn't that be true in a large org? Giving discounts to corporates always seems whacky to me.

Comment: @SteveBennett its called economics of scale. The time and resources SO has to spend on one large team is significantly smaller then what is has to spend on 100 small teams. Usually the provider and the client work out a deal that splits this economics of scale difference across the both of them. Resulting in lower costs for the big company and a comparable, to small companies, profit margin for SO in this case.

Comment: Also take into account that the products Stack Overflow is competing with for large companies might include custom deployments of open source software, or software offered at a fixed price for on-site installations. These are much more compelling options for large corporations than for small businesses, and to compete SE will probably have to offer a more reasonable pricing option.

Comment: @Luuklag Sure, that addresses the supply side, but the OP's comment ("prohibitively expensive for large organizations") was about the demand side. It doesn't inherently make sense that a per-user cost becomes "prohibitively expensive" simply because one has more users.

Comment: @SteveBennett "The fundamental logic here is a bit a weird: if $17/user is a reasonable price for a small organisation, why isn't it a reasonable price for a large one?" Additionally to what has been commented already I would also like to add that small organisations might only pay for power users while large organization might like to add everyone of their employees, even if many of them don't really use it. The question is simply if the service is worth $17 per month and employee. For large organizations it might not be worth it.

Comment: $17 per user and month seems to be too much for thousands of users. For a couple of million dollars per year, could one even try to recreate the things for oneself?

Comment: @Trilarion at 5000 users, it costs just over 1M, at $200/hour one could put a dev to work for 5k+ hours. That would be roughly 3 dev's full-time for a year. (48 weeks, 40h/week). You would get somewhere with that I'd imagine.

Comment: @SteveBennett well that depends on how you look at it. It would be the same reason one would price a car at $4999,- instead of a flat $5K. As soon as people start talking numbers into the M's the psychological response is different then when they are talking numbers into the K's.

Comment: Any organization or person which governs itself will accept an offer which is considered to be in their best interest. So, if you have an offer, contact SO and make it. I know from personal experience that 2$ per low usage user per month for a group of 5000 is a good deal. You will have to discuss many details though. And reaching a decision maker in SO might be difficult, but that is what managers or purchase representatives do.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos That already might be the answer. There is no official price model for large volumes, but negotiations can result in a custom tailored deal.

Comment: @Luuklag Ugh I wish I made $200/hour...

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton, what you earn =/= what you cost to an employer. Take for example wage taxes, obligatory social premiums etc. Unless you live in an (under)developed country like the USA ofc.

Comment: @Luuklag Yeahhh I know, but still ;P

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton you can easily earn $200 an hour. Just work for one hour, then slack off for the rest of the time needed to get up to a total of $200 in earnings. **Disclaimer:** you might not be making $200 an hour for long using this method.

Comment: @Trilarion Yes, I was thinking at least in part of people who might not post on a regular basis, but might occasionally need to read or direct questions to the help desk or something like that. It would be nice to have them in the system, but I'm not sure it's worth $204 a year for them to use it only a couple of times.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if someone from SO/SE contacted the several leads that revealed themselves in the thread, and how long it took them to do so!

Comment: Do you need any features that aren't provided by the lower pricing levels?

Comment: @jpmc26 Yeah, I kind of do.

Comment: @Luuklag _Holy crap_ that's almost 10 times what I earn! I guess that's what I get for working in IT at a small company in rural Australia :( Maybe I should move...

Comment: @Clonkex mind, the "real cost" of employing you for your employer is probably close to 2x what you earn. And CoL makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There does not seem to be a pricing model for large organizations on the [pricing page](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/pricing) outside the $17 per month and user.

However, as [Jose Antonio Dura Olmos](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385970/does-stack-overflow-for-teams-have-a-pricing-model-that-supports-large-organizat?noredirect=1#comment702888_385970) already mentioned, it's likely they would be open to custom deals and negotiations. Just contact them through the usual channels and tell them about your specific requirements (many users, potentially not very active ones) and ask them to make you an offer or make an offer to them and see how it develops.

There is some business logic for lower rates for larger organizations because:

- it would be a large volume deal, StackExchange unlikely want to miss out on it
- the larger the organization, the higher the fraction of rather inactive users (I guess)
- scaling effects on both sides, ...

How much lower (if at all) is up to negotiations.

Comment: Good point. It would be nice if SE gave at least some indication as to how much they would be willing to be flexible though.

Comment: Many companies with enterprise SaaS products will clearly state that custom-pricing threshold (e.g. "need more than 5000 employees? contact us for pricing").  Kinda surprised that's not the case with Stack Overflow for Teams.

Comment: @EJoshuaS "...how much they would be willing to be flexible..." Maybe they don't know for themselves until they see an offer. How much do you think would this service save for your organization? It's difficult to estimate, I guess.