# These SO Teams ads are getting out of hand!

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, advertising

The image speaks for itself.

[image: An overexcited advertisement]

There is an ad targeting my confidential questions.  Good job, SO! You managed to read my inner heart just like all other advertisers. This is actually a non-trashy ad, and I deeply appreciate the ability to get rid of it with the handy `X` button.

But I feel like there shouldn't be an ad about asking private questions as a dialog on the answer box.

Is this a bug, or a feature?

---

After seeing [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386422/disclosure-if-you-place-ads-like-normal-information?noredirect=1&lq=1), I must respond.  My intent with this post is **not** to extract a disclosure from a for-profit company!  I just want ads targeted towards question-askers to not be on the answer box.  I couldn't care less about what SO wants to advertise me. I just ignore it anyway :).

---

It seems people are saying "Oh hey, lets stop SO from advertising!
NO NO NO NO. SO, a for-profit company, has as much right as anyone else to advertise.  **THIS QUESTION IS NOT ABOUT THE ADVERTISEMENT AT ALL**.  I am merely requesting that you don't try to get me to pay to *ask* questions when I want to *answer* questions.  The question/answer mismatch breaks the flow of the SO experience.

Comment: First in the footer, and then left side menu, and then over the main content, after that in the top bar and now in between question and answer. The only place remaining is the community bulletin.

Comment: Given how heavily they're pushing SO for Teams lately, it's actually a little surprising that no one from SE has responded to [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385970/does-stack-overflow-for-teams-have-a-pricing-model-that-supports-large-organizat) yet.

Comment: what happened to the discussion here?  I see no chat link

Comment: Were the comments deleted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<s>Sorry, but we're not planning on removing that notification at this time. We understand that Teams does not apply to all of our users, which is why we included the option to dismiss the ad</s>

The ad has now been removed.

Comment: There's this thing in the GDPR that says that an "Opt-out" isn't acceptable... Now I realize that this isn't a privacy issue, but this basically made that ad "opt-out". Is that fact stored somewhere? Or will we have to "opt-out" every time we load that page? It's not exactly top UX to have to dismiss ads.

Comment: @mackycheese21 We've removed the ads.

Comment: Is that why it was moved to the "announcement" banner?

Comment: Just keep abusing tools that are meant to inform the user of new things to display teams/jobs instead. yeah, that's a great way to get people to adblock the very things you use to let people know something new exists.

Comment: When I view StackOverflow a [different teams ad](https://i.imgur.com/JUP8ISH.png) is still at the top of every page.

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic the keyword is "different". That's a different campaign. At least it doesn't attempt to get users to create teams to answer questions.

Comment: @Zoe oh sorry. I thought it was a mistake and they meant to remove all the dismiss-able teams ads.